# jquery slideToggle work bad on backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm using slideToggle() function to make a dropdown menu.

My backbone code is:

```
events: {
     "mouseover .dropdownColl"  :   "toggleColl"
},
toggleColl: function(e) {
    $('.dropdownAbout .sub_navigation').stop(true, true).slideUp('fast'); 
},
...
```

and the html code:

```
<li class="dropdownColl">
   <a>menu</a>
   <ul class="sub_navigation">
      <li><a href="#">voice 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">voice 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">voice 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">voice 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">voice 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

i've got two problems: the first is that when my mouse is over the li.dropdownColl my slideToggle on sub_navigation works but when the mouse is over the a tag, my sub_navigation make slideDown ..and I don't know why. Second, when I make slideToggle and my mouse goes on ul.subnavigation > li the ul make slideDown again. I try to make it in a normal html page and it works fine, but on backbones i've got problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You should read about **event propagation & delegation & bubbling** in javascript.
This question & answer might be a place to start [What is event bubbling and capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)